# Search for word "null" in mysql field

Tags: php, mysql, sql, null

I'm using phpmyadmin and I'm trying to update all fields that contain the word 'null' (which came from javascript if you're wondering).

```
update profile inner join member_info on Username=l_ID
set FirstName= Nname_f, 
LastName=Nname_l 
WHERE FirstName = "null"
```

But it says "FirstName" cannot be null.  The odd thing is select...where..."null" DID work.

I'm trying to pull the names from member_info table to any names in Profile that contain the literal string "null"

(this is what I get)

```
#1048 - Column 'FirstName' cannot be null
UPDATE profile INNER JOIN member_info ON Username = l_ID SET FirstName = Nname_f,
LastName = Nname_l WHERE FirstName LIKE  "null"
```

Comment: just to be sure, you wrote 'null' and not "null" (single quote and not double ones)

Comment: If it is the text "null" then you could use `WHERE FirstName LIKE "%null%"` or just `LIKE "null"` without %s

Comment: it IS the literal string "null".  but what is the different in mysql between = 'null' and = "null"?

Comment: @TheNytangel I actually tried that and it didn't work. I even tried REGEXP

Comment: If your second table contains all the first names anyhow, why just replace the ones where it is null? Why not just run it for the whole table and skip the where condition altogether?

Comment: @Fluffeh the reason is that the javascript app has their name as they typed it, and the other table is an older record that a "manager" typed, so I'm "falling back" on member_info, but profile is newer and "better" (except when they left it blank)

Comment: @Gar MySQL normally does "it's own thing" wrt quotes, so unless ANSI Quotes are enabled, `"null"` represents a string .. go figure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My hypothesis based on the symptoms that the WHERE matched a record, but the SET failed to update the record:

1. The *string* `"null"` is stored in FirstName (or else the `FirstName = "null"` would not match and, after the updates, it's a given), and;
2. Nname_f happens to be NULL so the assignment fails (presumably because FirstName is declared to be non-NULL). Whoops!

I would *suggest* fixing FirstName's definition/data before continuing. That is, decide if it *can* be NULL or not - and if it can (which it sounds like it should be), change the definition (so that FirstName is NULLABLE) and run a one-time conversion from `"null"` -> NULL.

Alternatively, hack it with `set FirstName = ISNULL(Nname_f, "null")` or similar to automatically convert from NULL - so that this `"null"` literal is used consistently. Ick!

A third option is to also declare `Nname_f` NOT NULLABLE - and make sure that it does not contain any NULLs, of course -  so that the above NULL assignment is not possible.

Comment: This is interesting and could explain why the original "select" without the join worked.  from the error 1048 can we tell whether it's a syntax issue or whether it failed while running?

Comment: @AwokeKnowing It fails while running - it's a violation of the value being inserted. If there were no NULL values then it would have likely succeeded. Consider a NULL constraint check like a user-added constraint: `isNotNull(x)` - one has to *know* `x` before being able to ask if the value is valid. This is different from a grievously incompatible type error.

Comment: you were right, there was 1 stray NULL in member_table that made the whole query fail.

Answer (score 1):

Use `IS NULL` :

```
update profile inner join member_info on Username=l_ID
set FirstName= Nname_f, 
LastName=Nname_l 
WHERE FirstName IS NULL
```

Comment: Based on the question, the OPs fields may actually contain the string value "null" which just makes me shudder.

Comment: Fluffeh you're correct.  they were supposed to have names, but when the names box was empty, the javscript app ended up sending the literal string "null", which is exactly what is in those fields.

Comment: Yes, the original title said 'Search for word "null"'. You clearly did not even read the question properly. I can't believe you got two upvotes.